# Orion Iot/Idas has reached the maximum mongo pool

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

We are using **Idas**/**Orion**/**Mongo**(docker build) and **Cygnus** together in order to send data to Ckan and Cosmos.

We simulated 100 sensors that send data each 3 minutes, This approach stopped working after 2 days, I've checked both IDAS and Orion logs and see these Mongodb erros in the logs, there is not any notification coming both of the components no more.

**Idas log:**

```
failed time=2016-05-25T11:30:13,852.191UTC | lvl=ERROR | comp=iota:Manager | op=checkIndexes | file=[140414053451808:admin_service.cc:148] | msg=Check configuration, error in checkIndexes DBException can't connect couldn't connect to server 172.17.0.2:27017 (172.17.0.2), connection attempt failed
time=2016-05-25T11:30:13,853.966UTC | lvl=ERROR | comp=iota:Manager | op=conn | file=[140414053451808:mongo_connection.cc:254] | msg=It has reached the maximum mongo pool
time=2016-05-25T11:30:13,853.993UTC | lvl=ERROR | comp=iota:Manager | op=conn | file=[140414053451808:mongo_connection.cc:258] | msg=create a new con
```

**Orion log:**

```
time=2016-05-25T11:30:04.948UTC | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | from=N/A | function=main | comp=Orion | msg=contextBroker.cpp[1719]: Orion Context Broker is running
time=2016-05-25T11:30:04.964UTC | lvl=ERROR | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | from=N/A | function=mongoConnect | comp=Orion | msg=mongoConnectionPool.cpp[140]: Database Startup Error (cannot connect to mongo - doing 100 retries with a 1000 microsecond interval)
time=2016-05-25T11:30:05.969UTC | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | from=N/A | function=mongoConnect | comp=Orion | msg=mongoConnectionPool.cpp[205]: Successful connection to database
time=2016-05-25T11:30:05.970UTC | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | from=N/A | function=setWriteConcern | comp=Orion | msg=connectionOperations.cpp[681]: Database Operation Successful (setWriteConcern: 1)
time=2016-05-25T11:30:05.970UTC | lvl=INFO | trans=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | from=N/A | function=getWriteConcern | comp=Orion | msg=connectionOperations.cpp[724]: Database Operation Successful (getWriteConcern)
```

`

Do you think that this is related with the number of data that is being sent to Idas? and mongodb stopped due to maximum connections exceeding?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orion shows the `cannot connect to mongo - doing 100 retries with a 1000 microsecond interval` error when the DB cannot be accessed, e.g. when the mongod server is down. I'm not an expert on IDAS, but I'd say that `couldn't connect to server 172.17.0.2:27017 (172.17.0.2), connection attempt failed` error is poiting to the same cause.

Thus, the solution to the problem is to ensure that MongoDB is up and running and accesible from Orion and IDAS.

Comment: our mongodb connections were working properly before we got this disk size image, investigated this and it turns out that this problem was because of the disk size  that mongodb was lacking.
changed the docker images location to a bigger space, now the system is normal again, thanks Fermin!